# How it is decided which certificate of a Certificate Authority will be used in a system certificate chain

Tags: security, certificates

I am looking for PKI (Public Key Infrastructure) knowledge and particularly at OS's built-in certificate chain list.

Of course on Windows the company decides which certificate will be built-in, but what about OpenSource operating system like Linux?

Comment: That's OS specific. Any particular one you're interested in? Unix is a family of operating systems, Linux is the kernel found in another family of operating systems.

Comment: What do you mean with CA? Certificate Authority?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas So it is...

Comment: @bersch Yes, it is.

Comment: That's an interesting point, you can assume that Trusted CA on proprietary UNIX are probably decided by the company who developed it. but for free OS like Ubuntu Debian or Centos, I have no clue how this list is established

Comment: It's up to the distribution maintainer. They can include any that they wish. But in practice, mostly the repackage Mozilla's list.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Arch Linux, and [other users](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=176745) told me that [it](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/ca-certificates) use the [debian package](http://packages.qa.debian.org/c/ca-certificates.html) which contains the certificate list compiled by [mozilla](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/governance/policies/security-group/certs/), [spi](http://www.spi-inc.org/) and [cacert](http://www.cacert.org/).

I am doubt that other Linux distro use the ca-certificate from Debian too.